# RuntimeError: expected scalar type Long but found Float - on the image processing

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

i am new to pytorch coding,I am trying to do image processing using pytorch but I am facing some issues.

```
model.to(device)

# Specity the loss function and optimizer
#criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

output = Variable(torch.randn(10, 120).float())
labels = Variable(torch.FloatTensor(10).uniform_(0, 120).long())

loss = criterion(output, labels.float())

optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.1)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[37], line 11
      8 output = Variable(torch.randn(10, 120).float())
      9 labels = Variable(torch.FloatTensor(10).uniform_(0, 120).long())
---> 11 loss = criterion(output, labels.float())
     13 optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.1)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\withGPU\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1518, in Module._wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1516     return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1517 else:
-> 1518     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\withGPU\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1527, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1522 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1523 # this function, and just call forward.
   1524 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1525         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1526         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1527     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1529 try:
   1530     result = None

File ~\anaconda3\envs\withGPU\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py:1179, in CrossEntropyLoss.forward(self, input, target)
   1178 def forward(self, input: Tensor, target: Tensor) -> Tensor:
-> 1179     return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
   1180                            ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction,
   1181                            label_smoothing=self.label_smoothing)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\withGPU\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py:3053, in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction, label_smoothing)
   3051 if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   3052     reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 3053 return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)

RuntimeError: expected scalar type Long but found Float
```

can anyone explain to me what error did I get from the above? The error seems to be showing the error is happening at crosse entropy?

I am actually trying to run images of the size [5, 3, 544, 688] using the UNet training model.

Here is my code where I am training my model...

```
- **Cell 1: contain Unet model**
```

```
model.to(device)

# Specity the loss function and optimizer
#criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

output = Variable(torch.randn(10, 120).float())
labels = Variable(torch.FloatTensor(10).uniform_(0, 120).long())

loss = criterion(output, labels.float())

optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.1)
```

```
def train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, data_loader, device):

    model.train()

    # Zero the performance stats for each epoch (set initial conditon - clear)
    running_loss = 0.0
    start_time = time.time()
    total = 0
    correct = 0
    

    
    for i, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(dataloaders['train']):
        inputs = inputs.to(device)
        print(inputs.shape)
        labels = labels.to(device).float()
        #labels = labels.reshape(-1).to(device)
        print(labels) # output: tensor([number of outputs depends on batch size], device='cuda:0')
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        #outputs = model(inputs.float())
        
        outputs = F.softmax(model(inputs.float()), dim=1)

        
        # Assuming labels are originally loaded as torch.Tensor
        # Convert labels to long type
        #labels = labels.long()

        
        # Flatten the labels if needed
        #labels = labels.reshape(-1)
        
        # Print shapes
        print("Inputs shape:", inputs.shape)
        print("Outputs shape:", outputs.shape)
        print("Labels shape:", labels.shape)
        
        
        loss = criterion(labels, torch.argmax(outputs, dim=1))
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
        accuracy = 100 * correct / total
    
        # Print performance statistics
        running_loss += loss.item()
        if i % 10 == 0:    # print every 10 batches
            batch_time = time.time()
            speed = (i+1)/(batch_time-start_time)
            print('[%5d] loss: %.3f, speed: %.2f, accuracy: %.2f %%' %
                  (i, running_loss, speed, accuracy))

            running_loss = 0.0
            total = 0
            correct = 0

    
def val_model(model, data_loader):

    model.val()

    start_time = time.time()
    total = 0
    correct = 0
      
    with torch.no_grad():
        for i, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(dataloaders['val']):
            inputs = inputs.to(device)
            labels = labels.to(device).long()
            inputs = inputs.to(device)
            labels = labels.to(device).long()

            # zero the parameter gradients
            #optimizer.zero_grad()

            # forward + backward + optimize
            outputs = model(inputs.float())

            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
            total += labels.size(0)
            correct += (predicted == labels).sum(dim=1).item()
        accuracy = 100 * correct / total
            
        print('Finished Testing')
        print('Testing accuracy: %.1f %%' %(accuracy))
```

```
num_epochs = 3
for epoch in range(num_epochs): 
    print("------------------ Training Epoch {} ------------------".format(epoch+1))
    
    train_one_epoch(model, optimizer,'train' , device)

    val_model(model, 'val')

print('Finished Training')
```

Thank you in advanced:)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
loss = criterion(output, labels)
```

`nn.CrossEntropy()` expects the true labels of the type `torch.int64`. Since, you have already converted your labels to long using the `.long()` function, the above correction should work fine.